# How to read property target using Input type range

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I'm trying to implement an `input range` slider on a component in React.

However, when I try to use the slider, I get this error whenever I move the slider and the site breaks, `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined".`

Here is what I've tried so far, any ideas of where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';
import Loader from './Loader';

class Leader extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            value: 3
        };
    }

componentDidMount(){
    //delays rendering for the css loader, which will appear for 1 second and will let the component load after
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({isLoading: false}), 1000);
}

handleSliderChange(event){
    this.setState({value: this.event.target.value});
}

render(){

    if(loading){
        return <Loader />
    }else{
        return(
            <Grid container gutter={24}>                

                <Grid item xs={12}>

                    <div className="questionDesc questionFadeIn sectionSeperator">
                        How much money do you want?
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input
                        type="range"
                        min="0"
                        max="5"
                        value={this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.handleSliderChange.bind(this)}
                        step="1" />
                    </div>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}
}

export default Leader;
```

Comment: try this onChange={this.handleSliderChange.bind(e)}, you pass the event

Comment: instead of `this.event.target.value` to `event.target.value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
handleSliderChange(event){
    this.setState({value: this.event.target.value});
}
```

Replace with

```
handleSliderChange(event){
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}
```